# Quadratic form positive semidefinite if limits in every direction are nonnegative?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Let
$$q(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = \sum_{i,j=1}^{n}a_{ij}{x_i}{x_j}, \quad a_{ij}\in \mathbb{R}.$$
be a quadratic form with real coefficients. 
Suppose that the limit is nonnegative in every direction. That is, for any unit vector $u$,
$$ \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} q(tu) \geq 0.$$
Is $q$ necessarily positive semidefinite?
If the condition is strengthened to 
$$ \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} q(tu) > 0,$$
is it necessary positive definite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: if the coefficients are constant, then you don't need the limit. Bilinearity allows to evacuate $t^2>0$, so all you get is

$\forall u\in\mathbb R^n\, q(u) = \langle Au,u\rangle\ge 0$ where $A$ is a square symetric matrix.